# ResponseEntity for Generic Object not giving empty response

Tags: java, spring-boot, response-entity

When returning the response from controller in ResponseEntity for class B.
But it returns empty json response. controller method is below:

```
 @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity testSave(@Valid @RequestBody ReqData req, BindingResult result)
    {
        B response;
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            response=generateBadRequestResponse(result);//response variable of B type holds value in its fields, but not sending in response
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response); //getting empty json in postman response
        }

 
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Whereas Class B is declared like this:

```
public class B <T> implements Serializable {

    private String message;
    private T body;
    private List<T> errorList= new ArrayList<>();
   
    //omitted unnecessary code for brevity
}
```

I tested the api from postman.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please update it again with a [mcve].

Comment: sorry,I don't get it, everything related to the problem is provided here. The controller method, the required model class and comment where I am facing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more details, a few scenarios it can happen:

1. generateBadRequestResponse returns null
2. no getters on B

Comment: for no.1 , it is okay. 2 is on the point. I was setting value from the constructor and hence, getter setters were omitted, now works fine

Comment: Don't answer unclear questions; flag them for closure instead.